# Question about evaluating team members

Tags: discussion

I need to know if there has ever been any question asked about different methods of periodically evaluating team members. If so, please provide me the links to some of those questions or tell me what tags they have been assigned. If this is not the right place to ask such question, which site is more appropriate? programmer.SE?

Answer (score 3):

There are currently [46 search results for "evaluate"](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&pagesize=50&q=evaluate%20is%3aquestion). Some cover evaluating team members, some cover job opportunities; they've got several differnt tags, depending on the details of the question.

If you have a question in mind, searching some particular key words or phrases from it may help you find more relevant results. Additionally, the Ask Question page suggests related questions as you type your question's title, and is often more helpful than the search feature.

You don't go into much detail about what you're looking for/want to ask, so I feel the need to warn you that questions "where every answer is equally valid" can be a challenge to fit into the Stack Exchange format. I'd suggest looking through the [help center](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/asking) before asking, and possibly proposing your question here on meta first for some feedback/discussion.